# WD Passport external HD connected but not recognized

Tags: 14.04, usb, hard-drive, external-hdd

I have a 1TB WD Passport External HD. It was working 2 days back and is in perfect condition(its a new one). Today, my HD stopped being detected on my Ubuntu machine. The light on the HD was blinking. I connected the HD to another Windows machine as well but it does not get detected there neither. The output of `lsusb` is:

```
Bus 002 Device 010: ID 1058:0810 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Even though this shows western digital being listed, the HD does not mount as a filesystem on my machine. I am using Ubuntu 14.04. Can somebody help me to debug this?

This is the information i got from dmesg:

```
➜  ~  dmesg | tail -30
[126666.666590] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[126666.697528] usb 1-1.4: new full-speed USB device number 59 using ehci-pci
[126666.799435] usb 1-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=0a5c, idProduct=217f
[126666.799439] usb 1-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[126666.799442] usb 1-1.4: Product: Broadcom Bluetooth Device
[126666.799444] usb 1-1.4: Manufacturer: Broadcom Corp
[126666.799445] usb 1-1.4: SerialNumber: 7CE9D3B78A2B
[126673.897500] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[126673.897709] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Radio type=0x1-0x2-0x0
[126674.167380] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[126674.167610] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Radio type=0x1-0x2-0x0
[126674.264911] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[126674.284028] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[127484.481636] usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 84 using ehci-pci
[127484.993681] usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 85 using ehci-pci
[127485.086713] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=1058, idProduct=0810
[127485.086717] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[127485.086718] usb 2-1.2: Product: My Passport 0810
[127485.086720] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: Western Digital
[127485.086721] usb 2-1.2: SerialNumber: 575839314131345532353338
[127485.086993] usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[127485.087087] scsi456 : usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0
[127486.086368] scsi 456:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WD       My Passport 0810 1049 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[127486.086731] scsi 456:0:0:1: Enclosure         WD       SES Device       1049 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[127486.090103] sd 456:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[127486.090245] ses 456:0:0:1: Attached Enclosure device
[127486.090396] ses 456:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 13
[127516.675224] usb 2-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 85 using ehci-pci
[127516.767987] ses 456:0:0:1: Failed to get diagnostic page 0x30000
[127516.768001] ses 456:0:0:1: Failed to bind enclosure -19



➜  ~  sudo smartctl --scan
/dev/sda -d scsi # /dev/sda, SCSI device




➜  ~  sudo smartctl -d scsi /dev/sda -a
smartctl 6.2 2013-07-26 r3841 [x86_64-linux-3.16.0-38-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

User Capacity:        128,035,676,160 bytes [128 GB]
Logical block size:   512 bytes
Logical block provisioning type unreported, LBPME=-1, LBPRZ=0
Rotation Rate:        Solid State Device
Serial number:        S0MUNEAC320201
Device type:          disk
Local Time is:        Wed May 27 12:10:27 2015 IST
SMART support is:     Unavailable - device lacks SMART capability.

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===

Error Counter logging not supported


[GLTSD (Global Logging Target Save Disable) set. Enable Save with '-S on']
Device does not support Self Test logging
```

Comment: Does the device have enough power? Post relevant portions of logfiles...

Comment: Probably it's got a problem with the USB cable or worse the hard disk, although it's new.

Comment: Run `dmesg | tail -30` a few seconds after you connect the external disk. Post the output. This will allow us to see if the kernel recognises the disk at all. You can also install smartmontools: sudo aptitude install smartmontools and run: sudo smartctl --scan and then post the output as well. If your disk is shown in the above command's output, run: sudo smartctl -d <type_shown_above> /dev/sdX -a and as usual, post the output.

Comment: **Tojo:** Did the answer below help?

Answer (score 1):

If it's a brand new hard disk that came with an enclosure: **return it to the store and get a new one under warranty.**

If you've mounted it yourself into an enclosure, use a different USB port/cable and if that doesn't help: same solution as above.

Comment: Don't thank me!  **;-)** If you like my answer, just click the little grey **☑** under the "0" now turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like my answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you *really* like my answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, go to http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask